# Can't find 'References' tab to add System.Windows.Forms

Tags: winforms, reference, messagebox, solution-explorer, add-references-dialog

Can someone show me how to add the system.windows.forms reference so I can create a simple dialogue box? Every resource I'm seeing tells me to just click on the references tab on the solution explorer to add it from a dropdown list but I don't see a references tab in the tree.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHjhg.png)

Comment: You created a .Net Core Project. Build a new Solution, choosing the .Net Framework template this time.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm just wondering though, both of those options have C# in the little icon, and I always chose the core project option because its first. Why would VS prevent you from using certain tools if you clearly want to work with C#?